# an alternative Quantmod ZigZag overlay

Tags: r, quantmod

i'm currently using `quantmod` ZigZag overlay and i noticed it is calculated a bit differently then the original overlay.
I've demonstrated the difference in the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YER0M.gif) of RDWR using ZigZag(5%) with `quantmod` and a with a different program. as you can see `quantmod` is missing allot of significant points peaks and highs.
you can also see the difference pretty clearly when using [StockCharts](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=RDWR&p=D&yr=0&mn=7&dy=0&id=p46452609438).

I think it's because of the way `quantmod` smooth the trend. the algorithm should be using both high & low values and not just an average price or some other regression.
i was wondering if `quantmod` or maybe `TTR` provide an alternative ZigZag overlay that will produced the desired output (illustrated in the upper part of the picture).

Thanks.

the code for displaying the `quantmod` output in the picture is

```
s<-get(getSymbols('rdwr'))["2012-07::"]
chart_Series(s)
add_TA(ZigZag(s,5),on=1)
```

Comment: FWIW, it works with `chartSeries` like this: `chartSeries(s); addZigZag(5)`, or in one step `chartSeries(s, TA="addZigZag(5)")`.  I think there is still some work to be done on the `chart_Series` framework...

Comment: Right you are ! z<-na.omit(ZigZag(s,5)); z<-rbind(z[findPeaks(z)],z[findValleys(z)]); z; SOLVED ! (didn't realize they have different implementation for the overlays in the new charting function). BTW, how can i draw the old overlay with chart_Series (@agstudy just solved me another issue by moving to the experimental function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `?ZigZag` says the input should be a high/low price series and you provided an OHLCVA series.  It works correctly if you provide a high/low series.

```
s <- getSymbols('rdwr', auto.assign=FALSE)
chart_Series(s, subset="2012-07::")
add_TA(ZigZag(s[,2:3],5),on=1)
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but `?ZigZag` is a little ambiguous.  It says `HL` should be an "Object that is coercible to xts or matrix and *contains* either a High-Low price series, or a Close price series.". [emphasis added].  Given that quantmod often subsets inputs with things like `HLC`, `Cl`, etc., it's seems reasonable to expect ZigZag to work with an OHLCVA object.

Comment: @GSee: *sigh* I can see how that might be confusing.