# How to show the data labels of a linear graph

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to plot data using `plotly` and trying to find out how to add labels to the graph over the years. If I hover over the line, I can see the value but I am unable to figure out how to make it visible instead of hovering. Below is the data point which I see when I hover over the line and I can't see the data value without hovering. Is there any way I could make 107.1753k visible without hovering?

[image]

I tried adding labels as suggested here but the data point is still not visible. 
[Plot data labels in a line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140938/plot-data-labels-in-a-line-chart)

Below is the code which I am using, I have added labels if you see.

```
library(plotly)


plot_ly(x = prodn$Year) %>%
  add_lines(y = prodn$TotalProduction , color = I("blue"), name = "Prod",label = prodn$TotalProduction) %>%
  add_lines(y = prodn$TotalImport, color = I("green"), name = "Import",label = prodn$TotalImport)
```

Sample Data as per recommendation:

```
Year    TotalProduction TotalExport TotalImport
2001    112768.8806    4866.6038    1978.7299
2002    109428.3061    3960.1241    1687.5429
2003    107175.2573    4301.3508    2504.397
2004    111209.887     4799.7895    2728.0004
2005    113149.8099    4994.2211    3046.0349
2006    116274.9659    4964.7269    3624.5976
2007    114663.5345    5916.3103    3634.6847
2008    117180.8669    8151.9115    3420.7679
2009    107492.3392    5909.6951    2263.8515
2010    108436.8148    8171.5675    1935.2687
```

Thank You for your help !

Comment: I don't think I fully understand, when you say *"make it visible instead of hovering"*, do you mean visible *always* (regardless of mouse location) instead of just when hovering? (If that's the case, you might find your answer at https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/.)

Comment: @r2evans  Thanks for the information..yes thats correct .. I would like to see the data for that year without hovering..I went through the link provided it plots the variable name instead of showing the values for that time period

Comment: Perhaps I'm completely mis-reading that page, but the text shown is the contents of a field, not the variable name. My point is that I believe you need to add a layer of text over your points, using `add_text`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly add a layer of text with `add_text`. Adapting (simplifying) one of the examples from https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#styling-text,

```r
library(plotly)
data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$gear == 4),]
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_markers()
p
```

[image: plotly without text annotations]

We can add a layer of all "values" at each point, though a value doesn't need to be the x or y that went into the point (or line) itself, as shown here:

```r
p %>% add_text(text = ~disp, textposition = "top right")
```

[image: plotly adding all labels]

You can override the data that is used in that layer:

```r
p %>% add_text(text = ~disp, textposition = "top right", data = data[1:3,])
```

[image: plotly adding subset of labels]

(BTW: you can include `%>% layout(showlegend = FALSE)` to hide the legend ... I kept it out to keep the demonstrative code trivial.)

Comment: Edited it to remove `textfont=t`, which I had originally copied over from the plotly example page, then removed.

Comment: @r2evans..Thank You so much for providing information, this is really helpful but I am receiving this error. Error: Must supply `x`, `y` and `text` attributes, when I add this to my current code p %>% add_text(textposition = "top right")

Comment: Did you add `text=` somewhere to your `plot_ly` or `add_text` calls? It doesn't know what field you want to display, you need to show it explicitly. (Note that I did it in the initial `plot_ly` call, in reality I think it does better in `add_text`. I've edited my answer to be clearer about what you need to add to your calls.)

Comment: Not sure if its problem at my end, but I am using the below code.                     plot_ly(x = prodn$Year) %>%
  add_lines(y = prodn$TotalProduction , color = I("blue"), name = "Prod",label = prodn$TotalProduction) %>%
  add_lines(y = prodn$TotalImport, color = I("green"), name = "Import",label = prodn$TotalImport)

p %>% add_text(text=prodn$TotalProduction , textposition = "top right")                                     still the error is the same not sure why

Comment: I can't help much more if I can't see a sample of your data. Can you add the out of `dput(head(prodn,n=10))` to your question? (If there are a lot more columns, subsetting them might be nice.)

Comment: Thank You for all your help ! I have added sample data if you could have a look at it once